# XSLT - how to group output by common child element value in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, grouping

I have an XML file like the below where I may have multiple records with a common child element like so:

```
<person>
  <name>Alice</name>
  <account>001</account>
</person>
<person>
  <name>Alice</name>
  <account>002</account>
</person>
```

How would I transform this to the below using XSLT 2.0?

```
<person>
  <name>Alice</name>
  <account>001,002</account>
</person>
```

I'm fairly new to XSLT so please excuse the potentially novice question. Any guidance would be appreciated here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to group XML elements by node value in XSLT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19759805/how-to-group-xml-elements-by-node-value-in-xslt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`for-each-group`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-for-each-group) to group the `person` elements, and the [`separator` attribute on `value-of`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#value-of) to build the comma-separated value:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="person" group-by="name">
  <person>
    <xsl:sequence select="name" /><!-- copy the name element -->
    <account>
      <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/account" separator="," />
    </account>
  </person>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

(assuming your current context node is the parent of the `person` elements - if it is not then you'll have to adjust the `for-each-group` `select` expression appropriately)

Comment: Thanks @Ian. You are correct, the current context node is the parent of `person`. I'll give this a go